# iOS: Master View -> Detail View (how to make Detail View editable)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am looking for a possibility to implement an editable Detail View. My App has a classic Master -> Detail View setup. The Apple Docs (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/EnablingEditModeinaViewController/EnablingEditModeinaViewController.html) mentions:

> If you would prefer to display a new set of views for editing, you should either present a new view controller or use a navigation controller to present the new views.

but how do I implement that? My idea is that an additional created "Editable View" could also be used for creating new objects. How do I connect such a new "Editable View" to my two current Views "Master View" and "Detail View"? It's more like a conceptual question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibility 1: Put the detail view controller into a navigation view controller. On a button tab push the view controller with the editing capability onto the navigation stack. If you are finished with the edit, save and pop to the detail view controller.

Possibility 2: Present the editing view controller as a modal view controller in the detail view controller. When you are finished with the editing, save and dismiss the modal view controller.

If you don't understand what I am writing you should buy a book and learn.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That was what I am looking for. I was already thinking about possibility 1. Possibility 2 could also be interesting.